# grep ending with wildcard find results that are not suitable

Tags: linux, grep, find

I want to find all files that starts with "libc".
For example these are the files I have:

```
root@956b8809ab66:/test# ll
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr  4 14:14 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Apr  4 14:14 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Apr  4 14:14 libc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Apr  4 14:14 libd
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Apr  4 14:14 libe
```

So I used this command:

```
find .  -type f  | grep  "libc*"
```

and I got files that not starts with "libc" for example:

```
root@956b8809ab66:/test# find .  -type f  | grep  "libc*"
./libd
./libe
./libc
```

It is not suitable for the meaning of `*` in regular expression and not for glob construct.

So why `grep` return these results?

Comment: Please post text, not screenshots. Can you reduce the output of the `find` to a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [@Janez Kuhar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66942143/5625547) pointed out `libc*` is treated as a regex. It will match all as shown in this [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GgDtk7/1)

[image]

---

If you want `find` to only show `libc*` as glob, I would recommend using [`-iname`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/230952/what-is-the-difference-when-using-find-between-name-and-iname)

```sh
find . -type f -iname "libc*"
```

---

As additional to [OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66942002/grep-ending-with-wildcard-find-results-that-are-not-suitable/66942208?noredirect=1#comment118329514_66942208):

> So does it mean that there is not different between "libc*" and "liba*" or "libf*"?

The `*` regex quantifier states:

> matches the previous token between **zero and unlimited times**, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

So yea, both `libc*`, `liba*` and `libf*` will give the same result because you're still saying that the last char (`a`/`f`) is optionally thus `lib` will match.

Comment: Thanks man, very helpful. So does it mean that there is not different between "libc*" and "liba*" or "libf*"? all these options will return the same results

Comment: Thanks. It seems strange to me that all these options will have the same results. Actually "libc*" will return same results as "lib.*". Maybe we miss something. But for now I don't know what. Thanks again

Comment: Not that strange if you ask me. For `lib.*` check: [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/LfEzLf/1). You're looking for `lib` and then **any character** - **zero and unlimited times**. So the'll all match again.

Answer (score 0):

Tl;dr version: use `find .  -type f -name 'libc*'`

There are a couple of things that will cause you a few difficulties; lets assume your find gives you the following (hypothetical) results.

```
$ find . -type f
./meh/library/alfa.py
./meh/bravolib/bravo.rb
./meh/libcharlie/charlie.c
./meh/libs/libc.so
./meh/libs/libm.so
./meh/mike/mikeslibc.so
```

Your `grep libc*' will return every single one of these lines. That grep essentially says to give you every line with 'lib' followed by zero or more c's. Every line above fulfils this criteria.

There are a couple of things you can do if you want to salvage your grep:

- Change * to .*; With this rather than matching zero or more of the previous character, you'll match zero or more of any character; a full stop represents any character.
- Check for a / before libc; this will filter out things like './mikeslibcstuff.so'
- Rather than check for *anything* check for anything that doesn't contain a forward slash; essentially [^/]* rather than .*.
- Anchor the pattern to the end of the string with a $.
- `grep '/libc[^/]$` would probably give you the results you're looking for.

Now; with all that, you're essentially trying to put a square peg into a round hole. Grep in this case isn't really the right tool for the job. The right tool is to use the filename wildcard matching functionality built into find with the -name or -iname flags:

`$ find . -name 'libc*'`